# How to turn off this hover menu at PhpStorm?

Tags: menu, hover, phpstorm

How to turn of following menu (at left bottom corner)? I am on MAC and using "hot corners" so this menu jumps every time i go for my left bottom "hot corner" Mac option and kills my ux.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, the only way is hiding the whole status bar.
Please vote for the issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-184948